# Python to pivot imported data in PowerBI, and save the pivot table as data/table in PowerBI

Tags: python, powerbi

Sample data as below.

```
Staff   Color Group BMI EQ
Amelia  Red 188 49
Elijah  Yellow  326 18
James   Blue    378 10
Benjamin    Red 144 34
Isabella    Red 269 10
Lucas   Yellow  159 48
Mason   Blue    496 48
```

I want to use above data, to produce a pivot table (by Python). The produced pivot table can be stored as a data source/table in PowerBI that I can use for building visuals.

Tried below:

```
at the beginning it gives: # 'dataset' holds the input data for this script
```

Then I tried to use Pandas to work with the 'dataset' but it's not right.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame('dataset')

print (df.groupby(['Color Group']).sum())
```

I also tried, only made it:

```
import pandas as pd
print (dataset.groupby(['Color Group']).sum())
```

There's no error message popped out. But I don't see the pivot table (please note that I want to save the pivot table as a data table in Power BI, like the original data imported, which is a data table in Power BI).

What's the right way?

[image]